# react router changing to current page with different params does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have some main routes as my basic pages and I change the content by the params of `GET` like in `post.html?pnum=8` useng the following code:

```
browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;
browserHistory.push("post.html?pnum=" + '8');
```

and I have the following routes:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={RouteA} />
  <Route path="index.html" component={RouteA} />
  <Route path="me.html" component={RouteB} />
  <Route path="post.html" component={RouteC} />
  <Route path="tag.html" component={RouteD} />
  <Route path="basket.html" component={RouteE} />
  <Route path="*" component={vars.currentRoute} />
</Router>
```

the problem is when I change through routes it works just right
but when I change only the params of the `browserHistory` the path changes but no changes applies to the page.

I want to do this for example:
the current path is: `"post.html?pnum=" + '8'` I want to change it to this `"post.html?pnum=" + '3'`

Comment: have you tried browserHistory.push(\`post.html?pnum=${pnum}\`); `?

Comment: @MichaelPloeckinger I don't think the problem is with the text of `push` method. as I mentioned it changes the path but not the contents.

Answer (score 1):

you need to listen on path change in

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if( this.props.location.search !== nextProps.location.search) {
       // fetch new data...
    }
```

then component will rerender.

Comment: on which component must this be written?

Comment: <Route path="post.html" component={RouteC} /> -> so in RouteC

Comment: but how should I relate between `RouteC` and it's child routes? `RouteC` is a class component includes the components that holds the content data in it's `state`.